# AS3 - algorithm to get pixels around a pixel

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, pixel

I need to detect the pixels located at a distance xxx around a specific pixel.

Are there any optimal algorithm to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: "detect pixels" for what? Average colour? Whether they're there?

Comment: By "detect" do you just need the algorithm to determine the `x,y` coordinates of all the pixels within a `radius` around the specific pixel? Or do you need that... AND a way to determine the color of each of those pixels... even if they are in different sprites/z-indexes (including the blending of layers due to partial transparency)?

Comment: I need detect the pixels around a pixel, in a certain radious. To get, or change the color.

Answer (score 0):

Go with circular expansion by walking around (0,0) while either coordinate is less than radius by absolute value, and add coordinates of the result to the pixel's. Should do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create two Point objects: (http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html) to get the (x,y) of the pixel that you want and the (x,y) of the object in around.

Then use the **Point.distance** to get a distance of the two objects. So, you have the pixels radius of the pixel.

I hope you have understood.

Comment: Hi biio, thanks for your help. I think your solution is valid, but it carries a big performance cost. I'll try it anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I have a bitmap with a width and a height:

```
centerX = width/2;
centerY = height/2;
radius = 250; // max radius to scan

for (j = 0; j < radius; j++) {

    for (i = 0; i < 360; i++) {

        radialX = centerX + sin(i) * j;
        radialY = centerY + cos(i) * j;

        // I can found the pixel data at: 
        radialX + (radialY * width);

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is :

-- Create a Sprite and draw a circle of the desired radius and fill

--  Create bitmapData and draw to it with that Sprite

-- iterate through the bitmapData and check for non-transparent pixels

-- when non-transparent is found create point and apply x,y offset

-- push that point into an array.

You should end up with an array of all pixel locations in a given radius.

I chose this approach because it sounds like you want to actually modify or utilize this data, and essentially you'd do that via a bitmapData. So this process would allow you to combine those processes potentially - if you compared and modified while iterating through both bitmapData's at the same time.